# How to create PostgreSQL read-only role with Ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, ansible-2.x, postgresql-9.5

I am creating a PostgreSQL user for a in internal dashboard where I want the user's access to the db to default to read-only.

I did some research, and it seems to be a bit complex to create a read-only user who also inherits access to any new tables, materialized views, etc.

So I think the simplest thing is just to set:

```
ALTER USER readuser SET default_transaction_read_only = on;
```

How do I set this using the Ansible PostgreSQL modules?

I'm not sure if I should be using the `postgresql_privs` or `postgresql_user` module. I tried experimenting with different values for the `priv` attribute, but couldn't get anything to work.

I'm aware that this is not guaranteed read-only, as the user could just change the type of transaction at runtime. However, it will be just fine for my usecase since security isn't an issue, I just want to protect against ignorant users accidentally modifying data. If someone is knowledgable enough to change their transaction, I'd rather assume they know what they're doing and have a legitimate reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if I should be using the postgresql_privs or
>   postgresql_user module. I tried experimenting with different values
>   for the priv attribute, but couldn't get anything to work.

Did you tried to revoke privs?:

```
# REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM reader
# "public" is the default schema. This also works for PostgreSQL 8.x.
- postgresql_privs: >
    db=library
    state=absent
    privs=INSERT,UPDATE
    objs=ALL_IN_SCHEMA
    role=reader
```

Note:

> To revoke only GRANT OPTION for a specific object, set state to
>   present and grant_option to no (see examples http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/postgresql_privs_module.html).
>
> Note that when revoking privileges from a role R, this role may still
>   have access via privileges granted to any role R is a member of
>   including PUBLIC.
>
> Note that when revoking privileges from a role R, you do so as the
>   user specified via login. If R has been granted the same privileges by
>   another user also, R can still access database objects via these
>   privileges.

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_privs_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-privs-module